# A template which is filled up by some variables (in PHP Web Forms)

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, cakephp, webforms

How can I have a template which is filled by some variables in Web Forms?

I already coded MVC applications; but now I have a project which is not MVC (it is just a web form); in MVC I could do the following for a template which is filled by some variables; can I do the sam ein web forms too?

**My code in MVC Codeigniter is as following;here my email_tempale file is a temple in which I get my variables which are; I'm looking for the equivalent in PHP Web Forms:**

```
  $mailData = array
                (
                'firtName' => $firtName,
                'lastName' => $lastName,
            );
        $msg = $this->load->view('email_template', $mailData, TRUE);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use CI for the new website? Then it works the same way.

Comment: No no framework has been used! The sample code I put is from one of my Codeigniter projects, but in this project no framework like CI has been used, just pure PHP; Im looking for the equivalent of my CI code into pure PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a template file too, so I think you can try this :

```
$mailData = array
                    (
                    'firtName' => $firtName,
                    'lastName' => $lastName,
                );
require_once "your template file path";
```

Then in your template file, put following lines in right place :

```
<?php echo $mailData['firstName']; ?>
<?php echo $mailData['lastName']; ?>
```

If you want to get the content of your template with rendered variables instead of its output, you can try this -

```
ob_start();
require_once "your template file path";
$msg = ob_get_contents ();
ob_end_clean ();
```

It could work, but I never tested it.